# FolderBrowserDialog open again on cancel

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

When i open the FolderBrowserDialog then click cancel it reopens again.
But, On the second FolderBrowserDialog when you click cancel again it properly closes.
And when you select a path on the second FolderBrowserDialog, It does or returns nothing
Can i stop the second FolderBrowserDialog on appearing when i click on cancel on the first?
I dont know why is it appearing. thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
Dim apppath
Try
    FolderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
    FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "C:\"
    FolderBrowserDialog1.Description = "Select File Location Path"
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        apppath = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    ElseIf FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel    Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(apppath & "apppath.txt", apppath, False)
    MessageBox.Show(apppath)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Location")
    Exit Sub
```

End Try

Comment: you are calling `ShowDialog` twice - both in the If and the Else, to stop it, dont call it twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Dim result as Windows.Forms.DialogResult = FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    apppath = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel    Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```